Error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 7b" when trying to startup Jira Data Center after downgrade
I have downgraded my Jira DC instance from 10.3.x (which uses DB password encryption) back to 10.0 (which uses plaintext on dbconfig.xml. When I try to startup the instance I get error below. Jira documentation doesn't mention this error message.

I have tried to encrypt the password as per https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracore/advanced-encryption-975040999.html but this fails.
I have tried directly adding the JSON object to dbconfig.xml but that didn't work either

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!
2024-12-26 21:08:30,382-0300 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.j.issue.index.DefaultIndexManager] Start to check for index consistency.
2024-12-26 21:08:30,384-0300 Caesium-1-4 WARN ServiceRunner     [c.a.j.issue.index.IndexConsistencyUtils] Index consistency check failed for index 'Issue': expectedCount=65; actualCount=0; tolerancePercentage=10, tolerance=10
2024-12-26 21:08:30,384-0300 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.j.issue.index.DefaultIndexManager] Index consistency check finished. indexConsistent: false; timeToCheckIndexConsistency: 1 ms
2024-12-26 21:08:30,384-0300 Caesium-1-4 WARN ServiceRunner     [c.a.jira.servlet.ApplicationStateResolverImpl] The search index is inconsistent. This node will report its status as ERROR. You will find information on how to resolve this problem here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-66970
2024-12-26 21:09:00,016-0300 Caesium-1-2 ERROR anonymous    New issue / add comment [c.a.d.c.p.ciphers.base64.Base64Cipher] Runtime Exception thrown when decrypting: {ATL_SECURED}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 7b
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:848)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:566)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:589)
    at com.atlassian.db.config.password.ciphers.base64.Base64Cipher.decodeFromString(Base64Cipher.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.db.config.password.ciphers.base64.Base64Cipher.decrypt(Base64Cipher.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.mail.server.managers.jira.EncryptionManager.decryptPassword(EncryptionManager.java:60)
    at com.atlassian.mail.server.managers.jira.AuthConfigMapper.toConfigurationData(AuthConfigMapper.java:117)
    at com.atlassian.mail.server.managers.jira.OFBizMailServerManager.constructMailServerImpl(OFBizMailServerManager.java:317)
    at com.atlassian.mail.server.managers.jira.OFBizMailServerManager.constructMailServer(OFBizMailServerManager.java:287)
    at com.atlassian.mail.server.managers.jira.OFBizMailServerManager.getMailServer(OFBizMailServerManager.java:131)
    at com.atlassian.jira.service.services.mail.MailFetcherService.getMailServer(MailFetcherService.java:512)
    at com.atlassian.jira.service.services.mail.MailFetcherService.runImpl(MailFetcherService.java:421)
    at com.atlassian.jira.service.services.file.AbstractMessageHandlingService.run(AbstractMessageHandlingService.java:234)
    at com.atlassian.jira.service.JiraServiceContainerImpl.run(JiraServiceContainerImpl.java:68)
    at com.atlassian.jira.service.ServiceRunner.runService(ServiceRunner.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.jira.service.ServiceRunner.runServiceId(ServiceRunner.java:44)
    at com.atlassian.jira.service.ServiceRunner.runJob(ServiceRunner.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.scheduler.core.JobLauncher.runJob(JobLauncher.java:134)
    at com.atlassian.scheduler.core.JobLauncher.launchAndBuildResponse(JobLauncher.java:106)
    at com.atlassian.scheduler.core.JobLauncher.launch(JobLauncher.java:90)
    at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.CaesiumSchedulerService.launchJob(CaesiumSchedulerService.java:500)
    at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.CaesiumSchedulerService.executeClusteredJob(CaesiumSchedulerService.java:495)
    at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.CaesiumSchedulerService.executeClusteredJobWithRecoveryGuard(CaesiumSchedulerService.java:519)
    at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.CaesiumSchedulerService.executeQueuedJob(CaesiumSchedulerService.java:415)
    at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.SchedulerQueueWorker.executeJob(SchedulerQueueWorker.java:66)
    at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.SchedulerQueueWorker.executeNextJob(SchedulerQueueWorker.java:60)
    at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.SchedulerQueueWorker.run(SchedulerQueueWorker.java:35)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


It looks like double base64 decoding is being attempted. Once by atlassian and once by java.util.Base64 right afterwards.

You wouldn't have updated your Prod instance from 10.0 to 10.3 without first testing on a Dev / Test instance first, right? Why no just dump the Dev / Test instance or roll it back to the prior snapshot?
